# Query for a node with a given class under a div given an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to query for all the `ul` with a given class say "dashboard-list" which is under a `div` with a given id, example id=myPanel.

```
<div id="myPanel" class="todo">
    <div>
        <ul class="dashboard-list">
            <li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="dashboard-list">
            <li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I do a jQuery query to get each `ul`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('#myPanel ul.dashboard-list')
```

Pure JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#myPanel ul.dashboard-list')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

With jQuery

```
$('#myPanel ul.dashboard-list');
```

Without jQuery

```
 var parentDiv =  document.getElementById('myPanel');

 var allUl = parentDiv.getElementsByClassName('dashboard-list');
```

Or

```
document.getElementById('myPanel').getElementsByClassName("dashboard-list");
```

First get the div with id `myPanel`' and get the `ul` by using class name `dashboard-list` under `mypanel` div